# Multi-track audio playback C++ / PortAudio

Tags: c++, audio

I am working on a synthesizer/live-coding application where I want to have multiple instances of the engine generate different sounds with different sequences. (aside: I have the synth engine working with MIDI input).
Let's say the user input to the console may look something like this:

```
track:1,sound:pad,seq:[70, sleep 0.25, 77, sleep 0.5]
track:2,sound:bass,seq:[30, sleep 0.125, 30, sleep 0.125, 31, sleep 0.5]
play
```

How can I interleave the timing of these two sets of events with the correct sleeps?

I feel like there has got to be some way to synchronize these two series of events, I don't know if the answer is multithreading or some other syncing mechanism. What area of programming should I be looking at? Apologies if this question is unclear or totally naive.

for example, I'm nearly certain the following would not do what I think it does:

```cpp
# after issuing play command, the following events are generated, which clearly does not interleave these timing events
while (true) {
    stream.noteOn(70, track1);
    bpmSleep(0.25, track1); // beats
    stream.noteOff(70, track1);
    stream.noteOn(77, track1);
    bpmSleep(0.5, track1);
    stream.noteOff(77, track1);
    stream.noteOn(30, track2);
    bpmSleep(0.125, track2);
    stream.noteOff(30, track2);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Convert your input data to the same representation as MIDI: event type, track, parameters, time.  Then sort the two tracks together by time, and process all the events: grab next event, sleep until the time that event is supposed to happen, repeat.

Comment: Interesting! Well, since with RtMidi I have external input support, perhaps I can experiment with a loopback, generating internal MIDI events and sending them to the input queue for processing. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Although on windows I had to download loopMIDI since RtMidi does not support virtual ports with Windows MM as a back end.

Comment: @Peter generating MIDI loopback works great, but I'm still confused about "sorting two tracks by time." Furthermore, if we grab an event and sleep until the time the event should happen, but another event should take place...then I guess the events are not sorted by time. I guess I am still confused about how time should be represented when two events overlap. Perhaps time could be represented as a delta between events. I guess I haven't thought hard enough about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your input data to the same representation as MIDI: event type, track, parameters, time. Then sort the two tracks together by time, and process all the events: grab next event, sleep until the time that event is supposed to happen, repeat.

This is really what MIDI is.  A scheduled event representation.  In MIDI, NOTE ON is a completely separate event from NOTE OFF, so an event doesn't even have a duration.  If you imagine each track as a sequence of discrete events, all you need to do is be sure each event has the data to know which track it belongs in, and you can process them all in one queue.

Note that sleep doesn't need a track.  It's the absence of events, not an event itself.  Also note that you don't even need two channels for this.  Its common to play multiple voices on the same channel.

```
// pseudocode
struct event {
    enum {NOTE_ON, NOTE_OFF} event_type;
    int note;
};

while(true) {
    ev = events.pop();
    bpmSleep(ev->time - now);
    if(ev->event_type == NOTE_ON)
       stream.noteOn(ev->note, ev->channel);
    else if(next_event->event_type == NOTE_OFF)
       stream.noteOff(ev->note, ev->channel);
}
```

Comment: I was able to get everything working tonight beautifully.  One thing I discovered is that "now" really means keeping track of timestamps. Starting patterns with timestamp 0 is crucial. Durations I threw out the window and decided instead to control envelope decay instead. Here is a the gist of it in C++ without all the scaffolding around it: https://gist.github.com/aparks5/2aff473c7ffae03222ca1db44a3e9383#file-notes-cpp

Comment: Fantastic!  Just one more note: since your event queue must always be sorted, you might switch the data structure to a `std::priority_queue`.  You'll definitely want to typedef this with the correct comparison function (be careful with the definition of "greater").